# Why am I receiving the gcm/fcm notification only when autostart permission is set to ON in android OS even after passing priority=high header?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Why am I receiving the gcm/fcm notification only when autostart permission is set to ON  in android OS even after passing priority=high header?

What are the reasons behind this? And How do I mitigate this problem? Festive season is starting and I need to send lots of notifications, so help quickly is appreciated.